# $S^n$ is a retract of $B^{n+1}\setminus{P}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I would like to prove that $S^n$ is a retract of $B^{n+1}\setminus{P}$ where $P$ is a non-empty subset of $B^{n+1}$ such that $P\cap S^{n}=\emptyset.$

So let $s\in P$ and define $f$ the continuous function that maps $(M,t)\to (1-t)s+tM$ from $S^n\times I\to B^{n+1}\setminus{s}.$

Now, if $\overline{f}:S^n\times (0,1]\to B^{n+1}$ is a homeomorphism then if I denote $\pi: S^n\times (0,1]\to S^n$ the function defined by $\pi((P,s))=P$ then $\pi\circ f^{-1}$ is a retract of $B^{n+1}\setminus{s}$ on $S^n.$

So I just need to prove that $\overline{f}$ is a homeomorphism but not sure how can I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your map $\bar{f}$ can also be interpreted as a map 
$$\bar{f}: B^{n+1} \setminus 0 \rightarrow B^{n+1} \setminus s$$ For any $x \in B^{n+1} \setminus 0$, write $x$ uniquely as $tM$ for $M \in S^n = \partial B^{n+1}$ and $t \in (0,1]$ and define $\bar{f}(tM) = (1-t)s + tM$.

There's an analogous unique decomposition (see below for why it is unique) of any point $x \in B^{n+1} \setminus s$ as the sum of $s$ and a line segment radiating from $s$, i.e. $s + t(M - s)$ for some $M \in S^n$ and $t \in (0,1]$.  But note that $s + t(M-s) = (1-t)s + tM = \bar{f}(tM)$, hence $\bar{f}$ is surjective.  The proof that this decomposition is unique is simultaneously the proof that $\bar{f}$ is injective:  if $(1-t)s + tM = (1-v)s + vN$, then we have $(v-t)s = tM - vN$ and

- if $v = t$ then $M = N$
- otherwise $|s| = \frac{|tM - vN|}{|t - v|} \geq  \frac{|tM - vM|}{|t - v|} = 1$ (inequality follows from triangle inequality) which is a contradiction.

So $\bar{f}$ is a bijection.

We want to show it's a homeomorphism, so let's look now at continuity.  Since we're working with Euclidean balls, we'll work with epsilon-delta definition.  Assume $s$ is not the center of the ball, because in that case $\bar{f}$ was the identity map to begin with and trivially a homeomorphism.

Consider that for any $x = tM, y = vN$, $$|\bar{f}(x) - \bar{f}(y)| = |(v-t)s + tM - vN| \leq |v-t||s| + |x-y| \leq (1 + |s|)|x-y|$$ 
(The first inequality is triangle, and the second one is the fact that the difference in magnitudes of the points is at most the distance between them).
This means that to keep $|\bar{f}(x) - \bar{f}(y)| < \epsilon$, all we have to do is keep $|x -y| < \frac{\epsilon}{1 + |s|}$

That shows continuity of $\bar{f}$.  To show continuity of $\bar{f}^{-1}$, use the unique decomposition discussed earlier to write it explicitly as $\bar{f}^{-1}\big(s + t(M-s)\big) = tM$ and attack it again with epsilon-delta. In particular you have for any $x = s + t(M-s), y= s + v(N-s)$ that $$|\bar{f}^{-1}(x) - \bar{f}^{-1}(y)| = |tM - vN| = |t(M-s) + s - v(N-s) - s + ts - vs| \leq |x - y| + |t-v||s|$$
Now you also have that $$|x -y| = |t(M-s) - v(N-s)| \geq |(t-v)(M-s)| \geq (1 - |s|)|t-v|$$ (distance is minimized when $M, N$ are parallel.  Substituting into the above we see that $$|\bar{f}^{-1}(x) - \bar{f}^{-1}(y)| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{1 - |s|}$$ which shows continuity of $\bar{f}^{-1}$.

As an aside, a useful result that follows from the above established homeomorphism (see the comments below for more explanation) is that $B^n \setminus P_1$ is homeomorphic to $B^n \setminus P_2$ for any sets of interior points $P_1, P_2$ with the same finite cardinality.  From there we can also see that $R^n$ with $k$ points removed is homeomorphic to $R^n$ with any other $k$ points removed, and the same goes for $S^n$.

Comment: Why did you change the map $\overline{f}?$

Comment: It's the same map, I'm just reinterpreting the domain. When we embed $S^n$  and $B^{n+1}$ in $(n+1)$-dimensional space, it's clear that $S^n \times (0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $B^{n+1} \setminus 0$ via $(M,t) \rightarrow tM$, so I am just factoring your $\bar{f}$ through $B^{n+1}$. I think it's more intuitive to work with the map that way.  Geometrically, we're trying to prove that any two $n$-dimensional balls with a point removed are homeomorphic.

Comment: very nice explanation. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped! 
I think is a very nice problem because it will make your life easier in the future:  anytime you are working with a ball that has an interior set removed, you can always assume WLOG that that set contains the origin.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. The fact that that two n-dimensional ball with a point removed are homeomorphic is also very cool. I suppose that it can be generalized to n points ?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely does generalize! I'll leave it to you to figure out the details, but a sketch is as follows:  
recall that our above homeomorphism restricted to the identity on the spherical boundary of the ball.  For each removed point in the first ball, we choose a target removed point in the second ball (so that there is a bijection between the removed points of the two balls).  We move the first point to the second in a way that it does not interact with any of the other points.

Comment: For this we employ the above homeomorphism: choose a path of finite length from the point to its destination such that an $\epsilon$ radius tube around the path does not contain any other removed points of the ball (possible since we have a finite number of points). Now image an $\epsilon$ radius ball around the point we are moving.  We have a homeomorphism which is the identity everywhere on $B^n$ except in this small ball, where it is our above discussed homeomorphism that fixes the boundary and moves the removed point from one place to another (that it fixes the boundary is crucial!!)

Comment: Applying maps like this repeatedly (we only need to do so finitely many times, since our path has finite length), we can inch the removed point along the path to its destination.  Since a finite composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, the ball in its original state and current state are homeomorphic.  Now repeat this process for the other points!!

Comment: Hum I have to think about it. It seems ingenious. Thank you again